# Firestore Reference data type to set Foreign keys

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

By **REFERENCE DATA TYPE** I mean the [**DATA TYPE**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) supported by FireStore. 
 **NOT**  document reference.

How to add a reference data type?

how to use Reference data type as a foreign key which refers to another document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually solved this and realized how to set and query using reference data type. I had known how to set it up as per the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Wanted to know if there was another method to query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DocumentReference object that refers to the document that you want to point to.  Simply add that as a field to the document that needs to reference it, just like any other String or number value.  The SDK will create a reference type field for it.

- Android: [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference)
- iOS: [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference)
- Web: [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)